# Why doesn't god show himself/herself to bad people?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma

If God showed himself herself to bad people that would set fear in their mind and there will be only peace and thats what we all want.
Why god only show themselves to the sincere only wouldn't it be more beneficial if God showed herself/himself to everyone?

Comment: Who say bad people can't see God We saw god every day but we don't believe that They are God we know that they are God

Comment: Why do you consider someone bad?It's becos the person did Apakaar to you isn't it?due to which  you develop a dwesha(dislike) towards that person, yet the same person is liked by someone else (bcos they have received upakaar from him/her).You develop liking(Priya bhaav)  towards those who satisfy your norms.No one can do upakaar or apakaar to God  so NO dwesa or Priya for God.Thus God is equally disposed says Gita 9.29

Comment: *samo ’ham sarva-bhuteshu na me dveshyo ’sti na priyah*......Iam equally disposed to all living beings; I am neither inimical nor partial to anyone

Comment: @Athrey - that statement is easily misunderstood. is a match referee inimical or partial to anyone ? No. But then why does he punish the foul-committers with yellow card and reward the victims with free throws or penalties ? It would seem like he is partial towards victims and inimical towards perpetrators - that's because he is. He rewards those who follow shastras and punishes those who don't.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that God doesn't show Himself to bad people. It is the impure mind of a person that is incapable of seeing God.

**Mind causes both bondage and liberation**

> It is the view of wise men that **the mind is the cause of both the
> bondage and liberation of embodied beings.** If the mind is attached to
> the Gunas of Prakriti and their products, it leads to bondage; but
> when it begins to feel delight and attraction for the Lord (Purusha),
> it leads to liberation. When the mind is freed from the impurities of
> lust and greed generated by the sense of ‘I’ and ‘mine’, it attains to
> purity and rests in equanimity, being unaffected by pleasure or pain.
> Then the Jiva, endowed with knowledge, renunciation and devotion,
> experiences in truth the Supreme Spirit transcending Nature (Prakriti)
> – Kevala (untouched by anything), eternal, self-effulgent, subtle,
> indivisible and unconcerned – as well as Prakriti with all its binding
> power destroyed.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.25.15-18**

Comment: But what I meant was god as a punisher for wrong doers, it will make society a more peaceful place it will set a fear in the mind of the wrong doers if god just showed himself/herself.